# Using inheritance for encapsulation with Android Views

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to get into Android development on Android development's terms. To this end, I don't want to push onto it a mental model that is largely based on WinForms development.

My problem is that I find Activities and their fragments too cluttered. There are interface implementations all over the place. There are type hierarchies that get smushed into my Activity files. I find it, to say the least, off putting. When I see examples on the developer.android.com site they seem to advocate this complex, everything in one massive file model.

At the same time, I realize that the demo code is just that, demo code. What's the right approach when working with Android elements?

For example, I would like to have a GridView to display some graphics and allow the user to click on them, or long press on an item to do something. I can do this within an Activity.java file, within a public static class Fragment nested in the Activity.java file. I can then implement the on tap and hold listeners. At this point, I feel that this is a rather muddy design.

Would it be Android-Idiomatic to have instead a class that that extends GridView with my specific implementations of the listeners? In this instance, if the GridView decided to navigate somewhere, it could.

The question really applies to any complex view within Android. ListFragment seems nicer since at least I'm getting a type hierarchy explicitly here. I can have the fragment react to various item events.

Comment: If you are expecting to reuse this , then I guess you should go with extending the GridView and creating your own version of it say MyGridView.

Comment: @Goel, I don't really expect to reuse the grid across Activities. My goal is to better structure the application and its encapsulation.

Comment: so what is your problem? interfaces, or too-many-interfaces or the java concept of inner classes? You always can roll you own style with one class per file. But alltogether, what is the exact problem other than your own taste of code?

Comment: @Virmundi: if you dont expect to reuse. then its totally upto your taste.. Do whatever you prefer. I do not understand the point of your question anymore. Its your personal choice.

Comment: @all, I admit that this is a taste thing. What I'm looking for is someone with either a lot of experience doing complex Android work to chime in, or someone to point me to idiomatic project designs. What I would love to see is an Android like Pet Shop project that came with JEE.